# ActionBarSherlock add second Action Bar to SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I have created an ActionBar with a tabbed view using a ViewPager implementation with ActionBarSherlock. This all works fine and I have a top bar on my screen with two tabs (Profile and Info), implemented with Fragments. However, this is only one part/activity (the main activity) of my application and now I want to add another menu/action bar at the bottom of the screen that navigates between the different parts of my application. So now I have the Main activity and I wanna end up with the following in the bottom action bar:

- Main Activity
- Settings Activity
- Help Activity

How can I integrate this bottom bar that will be displayed across my whole application? My current Activity is implemented as follows:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements  OnContactsFetchedListener { 

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
private TabHost mTabHost;

private String user;
private String token;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Hide the title bar (just shows "Minggler")
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String message = extras.getString("message");
        Utils.showToast(getApplicationContext(), message);
        String user = extras.getString("user");
        String token = extras.getString("token");
        if (token != null) {
            saveUniqueToken();
        }
    }

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    setContentView(mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Profile"),
            ContactsFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Info"),
            InformationFragment.class, null);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    getContactInfo(intent);
    getCallHistory();
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();

        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return (SherlockFragment)Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

}
```

And my layout is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone has got an idea of how to approach this? It might be a lot of effort, but thanks a lot!